# How do I determine the number of items I have stored in an array?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a string array of size `5`, and I have `n` elements in it. How could I determine `n`? I have tried `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])`, but that returns the size of the array, which is `5`. My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string array[5];
    array[0] = "pie";
    array[1] = ":P";
    array[2] = "YELLOW";
    cout << sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
}
```

Comment: The solution is under "Pass by reference" in the linked question

Comment: @M.M I kinda missed that point too. So... where's the FAQ to say "Use `std::vector`" :)

Comment: Yeah. Well if "misunderstanding" means "having sane expectations" :) Reopened

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I have a string array of size `5`, and I have `n` elements in it. How could I determine `n`?

`n` is 5. Your array has 5 elements, because you declared it to be an array of 5 strings. `array[3]` and `array[4]` are just empty strings (`""`), but they're still there, and completely valid elements.

If you want to count how many non-empty strings your array has, you could use e.g. [`std::count_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) with a lambda:

```
int numberOfNonEmptyStrings = count_if(begin(array), end(array),
                                       [](string const& s) { return !s.empty(); });
```

or a handmade loop:

```
int numberOfNonEmptyStrings = 0;
for (auto const& s : array)
    if (!s.empty())
        ++numberOfNonEmptyStrings;
```

Answer (score 6):

A built-in array, called a **raw array**, has no support for a dynamic length. It has a fixed length. For a declared array that fixed length can be found in many ways, including the not-very-safe C idiom you used.

---

`std::vector<`*Itemtype*`>` from the standard library (header `<vector>`), manages a raw array plus a dynamic length. And that's apparently exactly what you need. The internal array, called the vector “buffer”, is automatically replaced with a larger one as needed, so you do not even have to specify the capacity up front – you can just *add items to* the vector.

Adding items to a vector is usually done via a method called `push_back`, and finding the current number of items, the *length*, is usually done via the `size` method, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> a;
    a.push_back( "pie" );
    a.push_back( ":P" );
    a.push_back( "YELLOW" );
    cout << a.size() << endl;
}
```

But since `std::vector` supports initialization via a *brace initialization list*, you do not have to use `push_back` for known initial items:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> a = { "pie", ":P", "YELLOW" };
    cout << a.size() << endl;
}
```

A final refinement is to use `const` if it's not intended for that vector to change. This makes it easier to reason about the code. With `const` you see up front that none of all that code below will be changing this vector, so you can be sure of what values it provides at any point:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> const a = { "pie", ":P", "YELLOW" };
    cout << a.size() << endl;
}
```

Disclaimer: code not touched by compiler's dirty hands.

---

Where you really want a fixed size array, you should preferably use `std::array<`*Itemtype*`>`. It works well with a range-based loop. And it has a `size` method, like vectors, so you can do things like this:

```
#include <algorithm>        // std::count
#include <iostream>
#include <string>           // std::string
#include <array>            // std::array
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    array<string, 5> const a = { "pie", ":P", "YELLOW" };
    cout << "Fixed size: " << a.size() << endl;
    int const n_empty = count( begin( a ), end( a ), "" );
    cout << "Non-empty strings: " << a.size() - n_empty << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a variable which holds the value of how many strings you have stored so far, and update that variable when you store a string.

Alternatively you could use a standard container instead of a C-style array:

```
#include <vector>

// ... in main

vector<string> array;
array.push_back("pie");
array.push_back(":P");
array.push_back("YELLOW");
cout << array.size() << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard class `std::string` has methods `size` and `length` that return the number of characters in a string.

For example relative to your code snippet

```
array[0] = "pie";
array[1] = ":P";
array[2] = "YELLOW";
```

`array[0].size()` will return 3,

`array[1].size()` will return 2,

`array[2],size()` will return 6

Comment: I didn't mean the size of each element, I meant the number of elements that I stored in the array. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @clamchowder314 Are you unavle to add all sizes of all elements of the array?

Comment: I would like some code that would return `3`, the number of elements I have put into the array.